# Searching an array elements

Tags: java

I want to search and item of an array. if it found the integer value, then it should print 1 otherwise it prints "NOt". I came up with coed below but it didn't help. my question is there a way to let binnerySerach method accept integer?

```
while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data= inputStream.next();
            String [] token =data.split(",");



            for(int i =0; i<14;i++)
            {
            int sherchitem = 1+i;
            }

            Arrays.sort(token);

            int founditem= Arrays.binarySearch(token, sherchitem);


            if (founditem>-1)
            {
                System.out.println("1");
            }
            else{System.out.println("Not");}
```

Comment: Are you sure you should be using binary search?

Comment: what is the best way to search array element plz?

Comment: Well with Binary Search, you need to have a sorted array

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have integer array and i want to search each element of the array. by another array element. if the values are equal then it should print "equal" otherwise it print "Not"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this method, and pass it your array of integers, and the value you're looking for.

```
public static void searchArray(int[] values, int target){

    //Loop through the array and compare all the elements with the target
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        //If we find the target, print the success message
        if(values[i] == target) {
            System.out.println("found it at: " + );
            return;  //We can return out of the method
        }
    }

    //If we get down to here, we didn't find the target
    System.out.println("not");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary search will except the same type as the array. In this case, you've given it a `String[]`, so it expects a `String`.  You can either parse the data into integers, or the easier solution you can do:

```
int founditem= Arrays.binarySearch(token, String.valueOf(sherchitem));
```